# Android Studio: Gradle 'offline mode'

Tags: android, gradle, offline-mode

I've never had this problem in Android Studio, but today I saw this error
If I click "Enable" it doesn't work, and in the next error it tell me to disable this offline mode
What I've to do?

[image: error]

Comment: Restart your IDE

Comment: It doesn't work, same error if I restart my PC

Comment: check your net connection

Comment: make sure you have internet connection properly. Still you have problem then restart your studio by click on File -> "Invalidate caches / Restart"